# How to list updated products in Magmi?

Tags: magento, magmi

I have a CSV product list with about 13000 SKUs and I'm using MAGMI to manage it.

If I run MAGMI in UPDATE mode, it will only update existing products and skip new ones, exiting with (example) "info:Skus imported OK:21/21"...

Is there a way to know WHICH products were updated?

I feel a bit lazy about going through the code, so please have patience on me for this one...

Thanks in advance!
Paulo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a basic plugin that outputs the log for each item in the Magmi Log.

1) Create file in magmi root `plugins/extra/itemprocessors/basicitemlogger/basicitemlogger.php`

2) Open the file and paste in the following

```
<?php
/**
 * Class BasicItemLogger
 * @author Axertion
 *
 * Returns basic SKU for item in the Magmi output log.
*/ 
class Magmi_BasicItemLogger extends Magmi_ItemProcessor
{


    public function getPluginInfo()
    {
        return array(
            "name" => "Basic Item Logger",
            "author" => "Axertion",
            "version" => "0.0.1",
            "url"=> "http://axertion.com"
        );
    }
    static public function getCategory()
    {
        return "Input Data Preprocessing";
    }

    public function getPluginParams($params)
    {
    }

    public function initialize($params)
    {
    }

    public function processItemAfterId(&$item,$params)
    {   

        if($params['new'] != 1)
        {
            $this->log("Item {$item["sku"]} has been updated.", "info");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

3) In the Magmi UI, go to the `Configure Current Profile` section.  Enable the `Basic Item Logger v0.0.1` and click `Update Profile`.

4) The Runtime Infos pane will now list out each item that is NOT NEW and was updated, like this:

```
Basic Item Logger v0.0.1 - Item 123253221 has been updated.
Basic Item Logger v0.0.1 - Item 520448042 has been updated.
Basic Item Logger v0.0.1 - Item 606852342 has been updated.
Basic Item Logger v0.0.1 - Item 955884964 has been updated.
```

Furthermore, you can easily modify the plugin code (which is very basic) to write to a simple log file.  Magmi gives you access to the entire item object.  You can base can write some nifty logic based off the item column values, by using `$item['column_name']` within the `processItemAfterId()` method.  You can also use `processItemBeforeId()` to change the item object before it is processed by Magmi.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the MAGMI Mail Notifier Plugin? This one should be able to do this.

It would even be easier if you were managing the imports via a php-script & cron. Come back to me if you need help on this;

Cheerz
Simon

Comment: Hi Simon... I haven't tried the Notifier basically because documentation was "sparse" to say the least... ;)  I will give it a try as well though.  Thanks for the tip.